# Can I put details of evaluations results in the Appendix?

Tags: computer-science, paper-submission, evaluation, acm, network-analysis

I'm about to send a paper about performance optimization in the field of Cloud computing. My target conference has a limit of 10-pages for the main section with unlimited pages for appendixes/references. My question is whether it's a good idea to move small details of my evaluation results to the Appendixes (to save some pages for other stuff), or it's better to somehow fit them in the main section?

My current plan is to keep key important evaluation results in the main section (maybe only 1 or 2 graphs) and move every other messy stuff to the appendix, including comparison graphs, evaluation parameters, extracted latency/throughput data, and most importantly, details of scenarios that I considered for the evaluation.

Is this a good idea?

P.S: My adviser (who is far more experienced) is against this idea. He says: "you should only put things into Appendixes that if a reader misses them, they can still exactly understand what you did in your paper (e.g., proofs of theorems). Evaluation results are not in this category, and they need to be put in the main section." Of course, I agree with this argument, but my question is specifically about whether small details of evaluation experiments fit in this category or not.

Comment: Putting some nonessential details into the appendix is fair. The scenarios you considered are surely not nonessential.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper Alright. For scenarios, I'll keep explanation of scenarios in the main part. What about the details of the evaluation results? I have 3-4 pages of results (numbers/charts/graphs) for ~200 different scenarios that I tested to make sure my model is accurate.

Comment: If it's not possible to put all these details in the paper, you might have to do some compromises. Include the details that are most important for your story: anything that is suitable for giving an "overview", and interesting individual cases. Put everything else into the appendix.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper Makes a lot sense. Thanks for your advice, I'll appreciate it if you elaborate a bit more as an answer.

Comment: I can elaborate more in an answer, but I'm not sure what to add on top of what I wrote in my comments. Do you have any further questions?

Comment: @lighthousekeeper I can see from your profile that you are a professor in CS. As a dummy example, let's imagine you proposed a method for optimizing home wireless network speed. To evaluate the efficiency of your method with the situation that your method is not used, let's say you need to run a bunch of experiments in various scenarios. In the main section of your paper (e.g. in the evaluation section), of course, you will include high-level results/comparison, but would you also include details of your experiments (extra tables/numbers/graphs), or you prefer to include them in the appendix?

Comment: My general strategy is to have as many details in the paper as possible. Usually it's not possible to have *all* the details in the paper, due to page limits. The details that didn't make the cut then go to the appendix.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper thanks. Imagine another scenario, let's say there is no page limitation in the main section to include all the details: would you still include a handful of ugly, messy, big-fat-ass, half-page/full-page tables full of numbers in the main section (or you would include them in the appendixes)? Assuming that those details won't make sense for an average reader unless he/she wants to know small details of each experiment. - Happy new year by the way :-)

Comment: If the details are not important for supporting the story of the paper, I might still put them into an appendix. This is because overlong manuscripts can look scary to reviewers and might lead to the paper taking longer to be accepted. Happy new year, too!

Answer (score 1):

I think your advisor gives good advice.

But if you are sole author, you can probably write it as you like and wait for the response of reviewers of the conference papers. But if you are too far off the "standard" you risk a quick reject rather than a suggestion to change it.

If you are only a co-author you need to negotiate it, of cours.e

Comment: Do you think it's a terribly bad idea to put evaluation results in the appendix? As I said to Nicole, I have 3-4 pages of evaluation results, and I think putting all of them in the main section just makes my paper so unnecessarily messy!

Comment: Like any reviewer I'd need to see what you have actually written. But perhaps you really need to rethink the organization of your results. You might need to do that even if you put them in the appendix.

Answer (score -1):

Between the two of you, I'd go with whoever has more experience.

Comment: An ability to negotiate and resolve issues is super important skill for anyone who wants to succeed and get stuff done.  A lot of people think about that as, what do I want.  But it's  more important to identify what the person you're negotiating with wants and understand their reasons.  In a partnership like the one you're in, you need to size up that you can't win this argument because it really is guided by experience. Give in gracefully and move on to the next item.

Comment: Thanks for your insightful advice. I 100% agree with you and I think it's vital for junior researchers to learn how to effectively negotiate/communicate with all parties in a project (including their supervisor). I believe my case is a bit different though, as I'm currently completely on my own.

Comment: @linker You're not completely on your own. You have a supervisor. I don't understand why you think you're in some different special case where Nicole Hamilton's advice doesn't apply.

Comment: @linker Yes I believe there are irresponsible supervisors, but this isn't an issue raised in your question here. Your question is about a specific manuscript design choice. Your supervisor isn't absent on this topic - in fact they have already weighed in with an opinion. Maybe it's not the kind of advice you are looking for but it seems like they *are* responding.

Comment: @BryanKrause Exactly! the question is specifically about whether putting evaluation results in the appendix (considering the aforementioned criteria) is a good practice or not. Even though the topic is subjective in nature, I believe there should be some form of guidelines/best practices somewhere...

Comment: @Linker Yeah, the form of guidelines is mostly "listen to your supervisor" who has more experience.

Comment: @BryanKrause "listen to your supervisor" is not a "guideline"... What would you have to say, if I hadn't written that "P.S" in my question? What if I'm the supervisor and asking this question? (or even a junior researcher outside academia with no supervisor)

Comment: @linker I would say "you should only put things into appendices if a reader can still exactly understand what you did in your paper without them". Exactly which things fit that category cannot be given in a guideline, and that's why you ask your advisor.

Comment: @BryanKrause The point of this question, as I mentioned in the title, is about a very specific section of most CS papers: "details of evaluation results". Things like huge numeric tables, messy graphs, etc. I have a webpage in Github and put all graphs there, but I'm not sure if I should put them in the main paper or just leave them in the appendix. The main problem is that if I put them in the main section,I'll definitely exceed the page limit. I know this is a common practice in scientific magazines e.g. Nature, but I only saw this pattern in a few conference papers ... that's why I asked.